# EXCEL VBA How to catch the event when you create a new worksheet with CTRL+ Copy

Tags: excel, vba

How do I  catch the event of creating a new worksheet by pressing CTRL+ Copy(Ctrl+drag/drop an already existing Sheet)?

I want this event to trigger another macro that refreshes a combobox containing all the Worksheets' Names, so that it includes the new added sheet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Workbook_SheetActivate` event to get the sheet name to populate the combo. This event will fire when the new copy is created using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + **Drag/Drop** as it will activate and fire the `SheetActivate` event. This will go in the `ThisWorkbook` code area.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)  
    '
    ' your code here
    '
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. You could catch it with a Dictionary and some events.

Put this code in `ThisWorkbook` module:

```
Option Explicit
Public DicWk As New Dictionary 'dictionary of worksheets names
Public wk As Worksheet



Private Sub Workbook_Open()

For Each wk In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    DicWk.Add wk.Name, wk.Index
Next wk


End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

If DicWk.Exists(Sh.Name) = False Then
    MsgBox Sh.Name & " was not here before"
    'the sheet is a new one, do whatever
    ' your code...
    '....
    '
    '....
    '....
    '....
    '....
    '....
    '....
    '....

    'we have to update dictionary with all new sheets names.
    DicWk.RemoveAll 'clear dictionary

    For Each wk In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        DicWk.Add wk.Name, wk.Index
    Next wk
Else
    'the sheet already was here,
End If

End Sub



Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
If DicWk.Exists(Sh.Name) = False Then
    MsgBox Sh.Name & " had a different name before"
    'the sheet changed name, so is kind of a new one
    ' your code...
    '....
    '
    '....
    '....
    '....
    '....
    '....
    '....
    '....

    'we have to update dictionary with all new sheets names.
    DicWk.RemoveAll 'clear dictionary

    For Each wk In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        DicWk.Add wk.Name, wk.Index
    Next wk
Else
    'the sheet already was here,
End If

End Sub
```

It will catch if a new sheet is created every time, and it will catch if you change the name of a worksheet (but it will catch if when you change the name AND activate a different one).

Also, you must add a reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`

> **[Check or add an object library reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/how-to/check-or-add-an-object-library-reference)**